# Where did French writer Céline get his pen name from?

Tags: french-language, pseudonym, louis-ferdinand-celine

French author Louis-Ferdinand Destouches, the author of *Journey to the End of the Night*, used Céline, a French female first name as his pen name.  Any idea where he got it from?

Comment: Are you looking for something other than the readily discovered fact that it was one of his mother’s names?

Comment: @Spagirl  I didn't know that Marguerite Destouches, née Guillou, Céline's mother, had "Céline" as one of her names.  I knew that her mother was called Céline (Guillou, née Lesjean).  I guess I'm looking for a piece of evidence (letter, interview etc. by Céline himself or someone else accounting for the origin of his pen name.  Any research on the internet is made, I find, difficult by the parasitic interferences we get from Céline Dion and have to sort through.  I'd appreciate a reference for your find about his mother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the entry [LOUIS-FERDINAND CÉLINE, De Destouches à Céline](https://www.universalis.fr/encyclopedie/louis-ferdinand-celine/1-de-destouches-a-celine/) in the online *Encyclopædia Universalis*,

> c'est à sa grand-mère maternelle, Céline Guillou, qu'il empruntera son nom de plume

Literal translation: "it is from his maternal grandmother, Céline Guillou, that he will borrow his pen name".

In the French Wikipedia article about the author, [the first footnote](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis-Ferdinand_C%C3%A9line#cite_note-1) points out that "Céline"

> (...) est le prénom de sa grand-mère et l'un des prénoms de sa mère. cf.Pol Vandromme, *Céline*, Pardès, 2001, p. 114

In other words, it is the first name of his grandmother and one of his mother's names.